# jquery: selecting any checkbox, but using 'this' and filtered to specifc one clicked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Goal: To be able to allow only 2 of 4 checkboxes to be checked at a time. I see my problem in this function:

```
$(function () {
    var limit = 2;
    $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
        var clicked = this;
        var nCurrentlyChecked = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            if (nCurrentlyChecked > limit)
                alert('too many. after 'ok' should deselect the checkbox clicked');
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
                alert("good, should be able to select");
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

The issue is trying to be generic enough so that I'm not writing multiple functions that all do the same thing. By selecting 'any' checkbox with `$("input:check")` and using `this` within both results/actions, the function will either check/uncheck all checkboxes depending on what state the box was in when clicked.

So right now, this statement: `$(this).prop('checked', false);` after clicking 'ok' in the alert box will keep a checkbox from actually getting checked...it will check, alert and then resort to it's previous state but it does this from the first point out.

Likewise with the other statement and alert.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to say, "Hey, only uncheck this exact checkbox that called this function and ignore the other checkboxes on the page"

Without creating a function under a more specific selector for each checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.prop()` callback function:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', function (_, currentState) {
        return $("input:checkbox:checked").length > limit 
               ? !! alert('an error') 
               : currentState
    });
});
```

[in action](http://jsfiddle.net/VgPvA/).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with grouping properly in the `if` statement. You should only uncheck the box if there are too many checked.

```
$(function () {
    var limit = 2;
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        var clicked = this;
        var nCurrentlyChecked = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            if (nCurrentlyChecked > limit) {
                alert('too many. after "ok" should deselect the checkbox clicked');
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
        } else {
            alert("good, should be able to select");
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/73z6U/1/)

You shouldn't use `$(this).prop('checked', true)` in the `else` clause, because that runs when the user is unchecking a box, not checking one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a bit of confusion in your logic. I'd try re-writing it this way:

```
$(function () {
var limit = 2;
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
    var clicked = this;
    var nCurrentlyChecked = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
    if(nCurrentlyChecked > limit && $(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).prop('checked', false); // undo checked
    }
});
```

This prioritizes the check on whether your limit has been reached over whether your current element is checked, which is irrelevant if the limit hasn't been reached.